# Hide Default Controller name From Url that have Arguments - Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I use path-format of yii urls...
I want change this url

> mypage.com/site/profile/username/name

to

> mypage.com/profile/username/name

{site: defaultControler, profile: an Action, username: Argument, name: Argument's value
}

how can this done by urlManager in yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Add this rule `/profile/*` into your config.php in components urlManager part. Params like "username" should be forwarded automatically by Yii.

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '/profile/*' => array('/site/profile/'),
        ),
    ),
```

Also check your .htaccess and allow Rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Thanks, It's work! I just add '/profile/*' => array('/site/profile/'), in urlManager :)